# how to sorting column id and Column name

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I've uploaded the pdf document to the mysql database. but I do not pay attention when uploading data sorting techniques in alphabetical on the column name. 
then I want to sort the data in alphabetical pdf file for indexing.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC";
```

My problem is, how to be able to sort the records in the column names in alphabetical order alphabet and id columns can also be ordered starting with number 1? How to do it?

it is my source code :

```
<tr>
<td>No. </td>
<td>File Name</td>
<td>File Type</td>
<td>File Size(KB)</td>
<td>View</td>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC";

$result_set=mysql_query($sql);
$nomor=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
$nomor++;
{
    ?>
    <tr>

    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="fileupload/<?php echo $row['name']?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Do post the schema as something like the text of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: the technical id has nothing to do with ordering

Comment: Do you want to order the table first by name and then by id? is that what you're trying to do? Than use SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC

Comment: tadman - Ok guys in next post i will do it, post the text. Tks for suggestion

Comment: user3265427 - i trying it to make indexing data for using in search engine application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure I understand what you ask but if you want to order on name and or id simply do this

`$sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC";`

It will start by ordering on name then on Id. You will see a difference only if you have duplicate names.

Also you don't care about sorting when you insert data, as you don't care about indexing ordering. You index a field to be able to sort faster.

If you want to sort on name and on id then you have to use a variable

```
$sort = $_GET['sort'] ?: 'name'; // défaut sorting on name

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY $sort ASC"; //careful about SQL injection, protect $sort value with the escape method provided by your driver.
```

You have to give all information for sorting in GET parameters. Look into phpmyadmin URL you will see them.

Comment: I were use that query $sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC";

Comment: I were use that query $sql="SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC"; but result is field name can chronological and appropriate with alphabet, it is fix, but still problem in field id, in field id the first order is 22 but i want in first order is 1, so when i use query SELECT * FROM upload ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC; in field id still can not order. so how it solution in order to can reset field id from random to order?